# Can I use OpenGL for general purpose matrix multiplication?

Tags: opengl, matrix-multiplication

The MultMatrix appears to only multiply 4x4 matrices, which makes sense for OpenGL purposes, but I was wondering if a more general matrix multiplication function existed within OpenGL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as can be easily verified by looking at the [documentation](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/), including [the GL Shader Language](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/glsl/).  The largest matrix data type is a 4x4.

It is very true there is a whole craft of of getting GPUs to do more general purpose math, including string and text manipulation for e.g. cryptographic purposes, by using OpenGL primitives in very tricky ways.  However you asked for a general purpose matrix multiplication function.

[OpenCL is a somewhat different story](http://www.khronos.org/opencl/).  It doesn't have a multiply primitive, but it's designed for general numeric computation, so examples and libraries are very common.

You can also easily code a general matrix multiply for NVIDIA processors in [CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home_new.html).  Their tutorials include the design of such a routine.

Comment: You can always write your own in OpenGL, using two 2D float arrays, of course, but it's really not using the language for what it was designed for.

Comment: Using OpenGL (float buffers and whatnot) to perform a task such as general purpose matrix multiplication is often referred to as the "old school" GPGPU (general-purpose GPU) programming method. I reckon it's still possible to get things working (and working fast, because of how optimized the drivers and hardware are for graphics workloads) but there really are better tools available now. If your graphics algorithm somehow uses larger matrices it might make a *little* bit more sense to try this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people think, that legacy OpenGL's (up to OpenGL-2.1) matrix multiplication would be in some way faster. This is not the case. The fixed function pipeline matrix manipulation functions are all executed on the CPU and only update the GPU matrix register on demand before a drawing call.

There's no benefit in using OpenGL for doing matrix math multiplication. If you want do to GPGPU computing you must do this using either OpenCL or compute shaders and to actually benefit from it, it must be applied to a very well parallelized problem.

Comment: Although this answer doesn't necessarily answer the question being asked, I posit that it answers the question that *should have been* asked, and provides more value over the accepted answer.